# Error Creating Azure DevOps Project Wiki Page via API - HTTP 404 Issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps, I'm encountering an issue where I cannot create a Project Wiki page via the API. I'm attempting to create a Project Wiki page using the REST API, but I'm consistently receiving a 404 HTTP error. I'm executing this operation from a build pipeline using a bash task with the 'curl' command.

Here is the pipeline I'm using:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'

jobs:
- job: WikiJob
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - bash: |
      #!/bin/bash
      set -e

      API_VERSION=7.1

      # Get the current project from the pipeline context
      project=$(System.TeamProject)

      # Define the Wiki details
      wikiRepo=${project}.wiki

      url="$SystemURI/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/$wikiRepo/pages?path=my_page&api-version=$API_VERSION"
      
      echo URL $url

      # Prepare the content update request
      updateContent='{"content":"Foo Bar"}'

      # Update the content of the Wiki page with the 'ls -alt' output
      response=$(curl -i -X PUT \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data "$updateContent" \
        --url "$url")

      echo response $response
    env:
      SystemURI: $(System.CollectionUri)
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

I can confirm that the variables are correctly populated, and the Wiki defined in $wikiRepo does exist.

However, I consistently receive an HTTP code 404 and the following error message:
 `{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier e2b297b8-965a-4a29-8541-bfbc0e6314a0 does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitRepositoryNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server","typeKey":"GitRepositoryNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

Git repo mentioned in the error does not exist in the project.

The build service user has contributor permissions, which should allow it to add and edit Wiki pages.

The Wiki page `my_page` from the example does not exist. I expect the page to be created.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, Build Services can not access the wiki even if they are added as a Contributor. Try to use your PAT instead of `System.AccessToken`. Maybe this is a bug or not.., but this is a good case to be added here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps

Comment: I cannot use PAT, it redirects pipelines to 2way auth.

I have created a ticket:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Redacted/10502109

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following things to resolve the issue:

1. Ensure you have provided the correct URL of the Wiki repository that contains the right organization name, project name and repository name.
2. If you run the bash task in a classic build pipeline, ensure you have enabled the option "**Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**" on the job-level.

   [image]
3. On the Security hub of the Wiki, ensure the two identities "**`{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})`**" and "**`Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})`**" have the '**`Read`**' and '**`Contribute`**' permissions set to '**`Allow`**'.

   [image]

---

**EDIT:**

Try to change the bash task step like as below.

For the **`System.AccessToken`**, we recommend you explicitly map it as environment variable on the task. Then call the environment variable in the script instead of directly using **`System.AccessToken`** in the script. See "[**Use predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)".

```yaml
. . .
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Add new Wiki page'
      env:
        CollectionUri: $(System.CollectionUri)
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          API_VERSION=7.1
          project=$(System.TeamProject)
          wikiRepo=${project}.wiki
          personalAccessToken=$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
          url="$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wiki/wikis/$wikiRepo/pages?path=my_page&api-version=$API_VERSION"
          echo URL $url
          updateContent='{"content":"Foo Bar"}'

          response=$(curl -i -X PUT \
          -H "Authorization: Bearer $personalAccessToken" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          --data "$updateContent" \
          --url "$url")
          echo response $response
```

Comment: 1. The URL is correct. When I replace the patch value with the existing page I can open that URL in my browser and get Wiki page content.
2. This is a build pipeline, not the classic pipeline.
3. I was missing "Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})" permissions. After adding then the problem remains.

Comment: @MislavCosic, So, you run the jobs in a YAML pipeline, right? Can you provide the YAML file of the pipeline?

Comment: I have edited the original question to include the pipeline yaml file. Thanks.

Comment: @MislavCosic, I have updated my above answer with more suggestions. Check and try it.

Comment: I tried, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @MislavCosic, can you try to create a new pipeline with the same definition to see if it works?

Comment: recreated pipeline behaves the same.